# HCL Domino server - How to disable Mail relay?

Tags: ibm-domino, lotus-notes

Our Domino server is open for mail relay. I would like to disable it. I have made the necessary changes in the server configuration document but still its open for relay. Any help would be appreciated. I have attached the screenshot of configuration and the test result.

[Server Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNUOz.png)

[Test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJJil.png)

Comment: Your configuration looks ok. Did you do your test from outside of 151.117.*.* network? Did you restart the router or the complete server after the configuration changes?

Comment: I restarted router, SMTP, http, domino server and even the host. I performed the test using command prompt in the host machine 151.117.212.123

Comment: But your Router configuration ALLOWS relay from all 151.117.*.* addresses (Field "Exclude these connecting hosts from anti-relay checks")... This test makes no sense: Router works as designed/configured

Comment: What should be the value for the Field "Exclude these connecting hosts from anti-relay checks" so that our host server 151.117.212.123 disables relay ?

Comment: You just put in the ip addresses or hostnames that ARE allowed to relay. If nobody should be allowed to relay then leave this field empty

Comment: Just read the [documentation](https://help.hcltechsw.com/domino/11.0.0/conf_restrictingsmtpinboundrouting_c.html), lot of stuff to read but might help...